# How to disable "use strict" in JSHint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I'd like to eliminate the 'Missing "use strict" statement.' warning that JSHint shows in my .js files.  Now, I want to keep the rest of the functionality intact, and I want a global way to disable the "use strict;" thing, because inserting the "use strict" command into every file is not an option for me.

I haven't been able to find any solutions that don't involve adding "use strict;" to each file, so I'm hoping this question will point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `strict` option to `false`, for more details look http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict

> false - disable warnings about strict mode

---

> This option requires the code to run in ECMAScript 5's strict mode.
>   Strict mode is a way to opt in to a restricted variant of JavaScript.
>   Strict mode eliminates some JavaScript pitfalls that didn't cause
>   errors by changing them to produce errors. It also fixes mistakes that
>   made it difficult for the JavaScript engines to perform certain
>   optimizations.
>
> - "global" - there must be a "use strict"; directive at global level
> - "implied" - lint the code as if there is the "use strict"; directive
> - false - disable warnings about strict mode
> - true - there must be a "use
>     strict"; directive at function level;
>         this is preferable for scripts intended to be loaded in web
>         browsers directly because enabling strict mode globally
>         could adversely effect other scripts running on the same
>         page