# How to disbale 'use strict' for jshint in Atom

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, jshint, use-strict

I would like to disable JSHint warning "W097": use function form of 'use strict'.

I know I can place `/* jshint -W097 *`/ and `/* jshint node: true */`

But I don't want to manually add that on top of every page. Is there a way to disable from the source code or settings?

Much appreciated

Comment: You can [_configure_ JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/), you know that, right? How did you find the in-line settings without finding the global ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable "use strict" in JSHint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977344/how-to-disable-use-strict-in-jshint)

Comment: @vlaz from checking out this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462478/jslint-is-suddenly-reporting-use-the-function-form-of-use-strict

Comment: That post does list .jshintrc, though.

Comment: Yea i finally got it up and running witht the settings I wanted. But's it's only working on the project level. I'm messing with source code to see if i can disable it from the entire package

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `.jshintrc` file for your project or even for the whole atom installation. Assuming that you have jshint installed you can refer to [this article](https://atom.io/packages/atom-jshint) under the topic "Included features".

Comment: I've tried doing that with the jshintrc file but never worked. But i'll take a look at the README, thanks

Comment: I tried adding both /* jshint -W097 */ and /* jshint node: true */ but perhaps this isn't the right command

Answer (score 0):

I basically just copied and pasted all the options found [here](https://github.com/Joezo/atom-jshint/blob/master/.jshintrc) in my jshint file in my local project. From there I set false to strict and true to esnext